# How to permanently redirect a url with a .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to do a 301 permanent redirect from

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?search=samplesearch
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/used/search.php?search=samplesearch [301]
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer if you search stackoverflow for '[redirect htaccess 301](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect%20htaccess)'. If you want to see how it's done. Use your cPanel to create a permanent redirect and then open your htaccess file with a text editor or cpanel filemanager to view the code. Then you'll know how to mod the htaccess manually if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Use RewriteCond with %{THE_REQUEST}

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET \/search\.php\?search=samplesearch\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /used/search.php?search=samplesearch [R=301,L]
```

For more information about mod_rewrite variables this site may help you:
http://www.askapache.com/tools/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html